# showing zero for data not exist

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to show 0 if data not exist like in my example desired output. I have tried using numrows but still not working...sorry for bad code. Im still learning..any input is much appreciated

```
    for ($x = 2013; $x<=2017; $x++) 
    { 

        $result= $myDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$myDB->prefix("mydata")." WHERE year='$x' AND data_id=8");
                 $numrows = $myDB->getRowsNum($result);
                  while($row = $myDB->fetchArray($result))
                   {

                   $year=$row['year']; 
                  $total=$row['total']; 
                   echo "$year : $total <br />"; 
                   } 

     }
```

current output

```
    2013 : 456 
    2014 : 103
    2016 : 45 
    2017 : 34
```

desired output

```
    2013 : 456 
    2014 : 103
    2015 : 0
    2016 : 45 
    2017 : 34
```

i tried something like this and its not working

```
for ($x = 2013; $x<=2017; $x++) { 

$result= $myDB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$myDB->prefix("mydata")." WHERE year='$x' AND data_id=8");
 $numrows = $myDB->getRowsNum($result);
 while($row = $myDB->fetchArray($result))
     { 

       if ($numrows > 0) {
           $year=$row['year']; 
       $total=$row['total']; 
    echo "$year : $total <br />"; 
       }
    else
    {
        echo "$x : 0 <br />"; 
    }


    } 
    }
```

Comment: Move the `if ($numRows > 0)` **outside** the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if ($numrows > 0) {
 while($row = $myDB->fetchArray($result))
     { 
       $year=$row['year']; 
       $total=$row['total']; 
    echo "$year : $total <br />"; 
     }
}
    else
    {
        echo "$x : 0 <br />"; 
    }
```

do it like this